# I would like to find details of N41JA, an aircraft that flew in the 1970s

Tags: airport, airplane

I acquired a large group of photo negatives this week mainly of aerial photos from the 1970s in the northern California and San Francisco area. One of the photos has a plane with number N41JA. I traced this to a company in Santa Rosa. My ultimate goal is to try and find the photographer.  I have dates that the photos were supposedly taken. Is it possible to match the plane to the dates and to a person? I am looking for any information that might help me or suggestions on how I might proceed? Thank you.

Comment: Also known as [C-GTPB](https://www.airhistory.net/photo/296031/C-GTPB)

Answer (score 2):

that plane was operated by STOL Air Commuter, a small airline serving northern california from SFO International Airport in the early 1970's, now defunct.